# LinkedList memory limit exceeded

Tags: java, memory-leaks, linked-list

The problem is from Leetcode.

"Given a linked list and a value x, partition it such that all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x.
You should preserve the original relative order of the nodes in each of the two partitions."

My question is, why we must have the "right.next = null" line. Why it will give a "memory limit exceeded error" if I do not put a NULL to the end of the LinkedList?
Thanks in advance!

```
    public ListNode partition (ListNode head, int x) {
        if (head==null) return head;
        ListNode leftDummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode rightDummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode left = leftDummy;
        ListNode right = rightDummy;

        while (head!=null) {
            if (head.val < x) {
                left.next = head;
                left = head;
            } else {
                right.next = head;
                right = head;
            }
            head = head.next;
        }
        // merge the two
        right.next = null;     // WHY THIS LINE??
        left.next = rightDummy.next;
        return leftDummy.next;
    }
```

Comment: Without that like you are not partitioning the original list so my guess is when you merge them you are creating something N^2 the number of nodes you had. This is where using a debugger would help explain what you are doing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have two pointers, left and right with wich you are constructing the partitions. They always point to the last element of the respective partition. leftDummy and rightDummy are the beginnings of those partitions. So, in the end you should attach the last element of the left partition to the first element of the right one:

```
left.next = rightDummy.next;
```

And if the last element of the right partition used to point to some other element in the original list, you should correct that, otherwise you can get an infinite loop:

```
right.next = null;
```

Here's an example:

Your list: 1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 2
With x = 4, in the end you get two partitions:

```
leftDummy = 1 -> 2 = left
rightDummy = 5 -> 8 = right
```

But in the original list, the element containing 8 (now called right) pointed to 2, so if you try to iterate over the new list 1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 8, you actually get:

```
1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 2.....
```

So, you have to remove the reference to the "next" element in the right variable.

Comment: But, even though we have a circled linked list, we don't have a memory leak here. A circled list doesn't mean that we have them in the memory for infinite times. So still puzzled why there is a memory limit exceed.